# NATS creating duplicate inboxes for reply

Tags: c#, nats.io

I have been playing with NATS messaging, using the C# client. I create a message publisher that sends synchronous requests:

```
IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection();
Msg rsp = connection.Request("subject", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some text"));
```

I create multiple subscribers using a queue group:

```
IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection();
connection.SubscribeAsync(
    "subject",
    "queue",
    (sender, args) =>
    {
        connection.Publish(args.Message.Reply, new byte[] { 0x00 });
    });
```

All well and good. I can send multiple messages, each goes to one and only one subscriber, responses are sent.

If I start using multiple queue groups, however, things go wrong. Say I create 20 publishers, publishing using subjects "S1", "S2", "S3", ... For each publisher I create 5 subscribers, so the subscribers for the first publisher have a subject of "S1" and a queue name of "Q1" &c.

When I start a test app running with the 20 publishers each running in their own thread, things quickly stop working. Publishers hang while waiting for synchronous responses.

I added some tracing and it seems that the the reply token is being duplicated. So, for instance, two different subscribers receive messages specifying the same inbox for replies:

```
Subject=S3;Reply=_INBOX.C403F3CD707D0EA6F4B1167CE0;Payload=<some text>}
Subject=S4;Reply=_INBOX.C403F3CD707D0EA6F4B1167CE0;Payload=<some text>}
```

I'm guessing the reply can only go to one publisher, so the other one gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for raising this; the reply subject being duplicated was a bug. 
 A contributor recently added a [fix](https://github.com/nats-io/csharp-nats/pull/161) for this issue (stemming from how`Random` uses `Environment.TickCount` as a seed).

The fix is currently in master branch; I'll update this answer when a new release is cut.